# Get the address of a link from web browser to desktop application C#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, webbrowser-control

I have been trying to get the href of any link from the page displayed in web browser in my C# app. Is there any way that i can save the link to a panel or empty area by dragging it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the `AllowDrop` property on your control/form to true. Then handle the `DragOver` and `DragDrop` events of said control/form. The simplest proof-of concept is to check the data in the event with `e.Data.GetData("Text")`.

This worked with external browsers I tried as well as the WebBrowser control in .NET.

Here is an example using drag/drop for files: http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/drag-and-drop-files-with-c/.

Comment: Actually i am trying to drag the link into a ListBox as mentioned in the link provided by you, but my program is not entering the DragEnter/Drop functions after i drag a link from a C# browser to the ListBox. ALso i am trying to view the data with "e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Html).ToString()"

Comment: @jose It may not be entering those events because you missed the first part of my answer. You need to set the `AllowDrop` property on your target control/form to `true`.